# prototype to css

Tags: css, frameworks, prototyping

Is there a program or app that allows you to prototype a website then generate the css based on the prototype? Lets say there's a prototyping software that uses a grid, if I add a navigation widget on the grid, it will output the exact css as if it were on a real website. Is there a program or something like this? Thanks!

Comment: Way late, but http://www.sketchapp.com/features/ does this.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing sounds to me like a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor.

There's tons of those around such as [DreamWeaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html).

There's also a good question [here about prototyping tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112803/what-is-the-best-web-prototyping-tool).

As I recall, some of the guys on our last project used [Axure](http://www.axure.com/) to build prototypes/wireframes and this tool created HTML, CSS and JS as part of it's process. Not production ready code but a good starting point.

Comment: Well, I'm what I'm looking for is not a WYSIWYG editor. I think Axure may have the feature I'm looking for. I just want to be able to draw up the wireframe and have the css generated, no html tags. Thanks though i will check out Axure!